# Передача данных из одного Activity в два других Activity

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Имеются три активити. Из `Activity1` в `Activity2` передается ряд параметров с помощью `Intent.putExtra`

Activity1

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("ID", 123);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getIntExtra("ID",0);
```

Данные отлично передаются, все прям отлично, но вот потребовалось передать переменную ID еще и в `Activity3`. Как это можно реализовать и вообще возможно ли передать одну переменную сразу на два активити с помощью `Intent`?

Comment: Из какой активити открывается третья активити?

Comment: Activity 3 открывается из Activity2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу в несколько активити передать интент не получится никаким образом, так как в один момент времени может быть запущенна только одна активити, остальные условно не существуют и не могут принимать данные.

Вы можете передать еще один интент дальше по цепочке (из активити2 в активити3) или сохранить значение в внешнем хранилище (файл, бд, преференсы, синглтон), доступ к которому могут иметь любые активити, но для данных типа промежуточный id это несколько избыточно, на мой взгляд.